# gnuplot lua-tikz font to Arial

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, lua

In gnuplot lua-tikz, I would like to change all letters that appear in a figure (including labels, tics numbers) to Arial. I tried several patterns as

```
set term lua tikz tightboundingbox standalone font "Arial"
```

but non of them works...

I would like to know the solution to this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe the `font` parameter has to be a valid LaTeX font selector, e.g. `font '\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont'`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for your reply. Do you mean that it should be revised not by the gnuplot script, but by the generated latex script? It would be really helpful if you could show a explicit way!

Comment: @HenriMenke Following your suggestion, I manage to change the font for labels! But changing fonts for tics `set tics font "\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont"` did not work. What is the solution here?

Comment: It seems the tics font does not change since the numbers are considered as equations, say $0$ in the latex file generated from the gnuplot. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You could try `set format "%h"`. Maybe that will strip `$`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Great solution! One final question: is it possible to specify "Arial"? phv is not bad, but it would be great if I can set Arial...

Comment: Arial is a commercial font by Microsoft and not available as traditional TeX font. If you can compile the picture with `lualatex` or `xelatex` then you can try `set term lua tikz tightboundingbox standalone header '\usepackage{fontspec}' font '\fontspec{Arial}'`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Great solution! Finally, everything works perfectly. I will summarize your solution as follow, but please feel free to summarize by yourself because the beautiful solution belongs to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @HenriMenke 's solution, I managed to solve the problem!
I would like to summarize the proposed solutions. We have two approaches:

1. Use "phv": the font is more-or-less same as Helvetica/Arial but not exactly the same

```
set term lua tikz tightboundingbox standalone font '\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont'
```

2. Use "Arial": compile with xelatex or lualatex

```
set term lua tikz tightboundingbox standalone header '\usepackage{fontspec}" font "\fontspec{Arial}'
```